# Kitematic startup error on windows 10 home

Tags: docker, windows-10, kitematic

I just installed docker on my windows 10 home pc and I'm trying to start up kitematic but it keeps failing with and unexpected error `could not determine ip from docker-machine`. I've also attached a screenshot below. I can't seem to find a solution to this. [image]

Comment: So click one  of the two buttons (Retry Setup or Delete VM & Retry Setup).

Comment: I've tried. Severally

Comment: Docker for Windows comes with [system requirements](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/). Do you have Windows 10 Pro ?